# Can't play audio in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an audio tag inside body which contains an audio file.I want to play it when the body has finished loading.It plays in chrome but it fails to play in mozilla firefox.I tried to download the file and then play it with the local file but i got similar results.

**Here's the audio tag declaration in the html:**

```
<audio id="audio" src="http://jPlayer.org/audio/mp3/gbreggae-leadguitar.mp3"></audio>
```

**And here is the JS used to play the audio after the body loads:**

```
document.body.onload=function(){
             document.getElementById("audio").play();
            };
```

Comment: which version you are using? I can see this is working in latest version

Comment: what's your version?@Vineesh

Comment: mine is 54.0. its working in lower versions.not the higher ones

Comment: works fine in firefox 54.0.1 and 55.0b13 - so, how are you "serving" the page? http:? https:? file:?

Comment: file @JaromandaX

Comment: any errors in the **developer** tools console? (file works for me, only https wont)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **.ogg** format, i had same problem and this thing solved my problem.
see below:--
Hope it helps.

```html
<audio id="Green">
        <source src="assets/audio/Green.mp3" </source>
        <source src="assets/audio/Green.ogg">
    </audio>
```

Comment: can you please explain the reason why is it happening so?

Comment: its because support for .mp3 files is deprecated in mozilla from version 52 and above.supported files include .wav,.ogg and some others.you can accept Ashish's answer.He provided the right solution

Comment: `support for .mp3 files is deprecated in mozilla from version 52` is this documented, @RahulDas? there's no mention [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats#Browser_compatibility) - the only caveat is that the operating system must "support" mp3 playback

Comment: in my case, it fixed my problem so i tried to help you out. there could be another problem also which can cause this,so not sure about them.

Comment: yes @JaromandaX. checkout this link https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/fix-common-audio-and-video-issues

Comment: you need to install a third party software to play .mp3 files starting from v52

Comment: yes i can see that.i wont install a third party software just to play one file.i can achieve it by converting it to .ogg.

Comment: Thanks @RahulDas for the explanation.Ashish's solution alone didn't solved the problem.

Comment: :) @AshishMishra

Comment: @RahulDas - no, you do not need to install any third party software. MP3 playback relies on **platform decoders** - so, it depends on the operating system support, not any "third pary software"

Comment: @AakroshSharma - what operating system (and version of it) are you running?